# Save and Rename File based on location

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I have working code to:

1. Insert the Date, Company Name & Order Number into the proof at a specific location (data is pulled from the file location "C:\2020\My Company\Company Name\COM001 - 01\Layouts")
2. Determine the amount of pages in the document
3. Paste step 1 onto the other pages
4. Export the document as a .pdf

What I am trying to achieve, is before the .pdf is saved that the file is renamed (in this case COM001 - 01) adds a version indicator (" _v1") then saves the .cdr file and then runs the .pdf export function but does not overwrite the original.

I have been trying to adapt code I found on thespreadsheetguru.

The code adds the version indicator and exports the .pdf in the correct file location, but as soon as I open another file in a different location it will save it in the previous location instead.

Here is that piece of code: (I can upload the entire code if needed.)

```vb
Private Sub SaveNewVersion()
    'PURPOSE: Save file, if already exists add a new version indicator to filename

    Dim FolderPath, myPath, SaveName, SaveExt, VersionExt As String
    Dim Saved As Boolean
    Dim x As Long
    Saved = False
    x = 1

    'Version Indicator (change to liking)
    VersionExt = " _v"

    'Pull info about file
    On Error GoTo NotSavedYet
    myPath = ActiveDocument.FileName
    myFileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)
    FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
    SaveExt = "." & Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, "."))
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Determine Base File Name
    If InStr(1, myFileName, VersionExt) > 1 Then
        myArray = Split(myFileName, VersionExt)
        SaveName = myArray(0)
    Else
        SaveName = myFileName
    End If

    'Need a new version made
    Do While Saved = False
        If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt) = False Then
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt
            Saved = True
        Else
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Loop
    Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NotSavedYet:
    MsgBox "This file has not been initially saved. " & _
      "Cannot save a new version!", vbCritical, "Not Saved To Computer"
End Sub


Function FileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean
    'PURPOSE: Test to see if a file exists or not
    Dim TestStr As String
    'Test File Path (ie "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Test\book1.xlsm")
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Determine if File exists
    If TestStr = "" Then
        FileExist = False
    Else
        FileExist = True
    End If
End Function
```

I have a feeling the code is messing up in the "pull info about file section".

Comment: Use FSO to easily pull file name, path, extension. Then you can build out the path string however you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object

Comment: Nobody can debug your code for you. You have to tell us where the problem is and specifically what you need help with. Read this: http://cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: The title says that this is a Corel Draw specific problem but then you say that the problem is a simple filename\path problem. This could be narrowed down and you could remove all mention of Corel Draw because I don't see how it's relevant to your issue.

Comment: It is CorelDraw specific as Excel VBA is slightly different to CorelDraws etc. Also i am using the code through CorelDraw and not any other application

Comment: As far as the debugging is concerned i have stepped through the code numerous times, it is not broken it just does not do what i need it to do, which is pull the correct file path and then save the file using the correct order number and adding the variant indicator after it

Comment: VBA is identical in every host application. The only difference is the Host Object model. I only see two commands you are using from the Corel Draw object model and they have nothing to do with building a file path string.

Comment: When you are debugging you are looking at the string at each step. You want to look at the strings you are using to build the save as path right before the save. Change them to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the final path in a way that you can inspect it before you use it. Swap out this block of code here:

```
Dim newFileName as String
newFileName = FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt
Debug.Print newFileName 
If FileExist(newFileName) = False Then
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs newFileName 
    Saved = True
Else
    x = x + 1
End If
```

This will print the final filename to the Immediate Window before the save happens. If it is incorrect, change `newFileName` to be whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is where the issue is coming in as I thought, its pulling the file name but the folder path is returning a blank value, which is why i would assume that it is just saving it to the same folder regardless of its location and isnt able to check if the file exists. Going to try a few variations to see if i can get it to pull the correct filepath without messing with the version indicator section.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a simple issue regarding the File path not returning any information..

changed out this code and now it works perfectly

```
 On Error GoTo NotSavedYet
    myFile = ActiveDocument.FileName
    myPath = (ActiveDocument.FilePath)
    myFileName = Mid(myFile, InStrRev(myFile, "\") + 1, InStrRev(myFile, ".") - InStrRev(myFile, "\") - 1)
    FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
    SaveExt = "." & Right(myFile, Len(myFile) - InStrRev(myFile, "."))
    Debug.Print FolderPath
  On Error GoTo 0
```

Thanks @HackSlash for the tip, much appreciated